Correlation Coefficent is higher when likelihood of an event is lower, how does this occur?
I have different variables that I am interested in if they influence pass/fail rates.
To see what variables I might use as a leading indicator, I've pulled different variables such as "tutoring", "A student", "high income household".
Since the pass fail variable is binary and the variables tutoring, a student and high income are binary as well, I pulled the phi coefficient.
I've also looked at pass/fail rates as conditional probabilities of when tutoring, A student or high income is present.
For some of the variables, even though the average of conditional probabilities makes it seem much more likely to pass when the student has a variable present, the correlation is lower.
Is this possible? Can someone explain how this would occur? Or did I make a mistake somewhere with my math?


You have not stated how often the variable is present. For your first row, to get $\phi=0.06$, my unchecked quick calculations suggests the variable is present $0.05%$ of the time, while for your second row to get  $\phi=0.065$ my unchecked quick calculations suggests the variable is present $0.29%$ of the time, more than five times as often though still small.  Perhaps I am misunderstanding or making some other error.  If the variable were present half the time in both cases, I seem to get $\phi \approx 0.429$ for the first row and $\approx 0.265$ for the second row, nearer your intuition.

yes, the % of time the variable is present is about what you've said, but the conditional probabilities make it seem like the correlation would be stronger for the top one, but correlation is lower. Can you explain how that makes sense? Is it just how the percent the variable is present overall shakes out?

The counter-intuitive result on the correlations is indeed largely a consequence of the very different percentages of time the variable is present.
